# Change default monitor for Mathematica?

Tags: front-end, windows

Even though I do all of my work on my center monitor, and open Mathematica on my center monitor, and keep my Mathematica window in the center monitor, it keeps opening new windows on my right monitor. It even has the input assistant come up with suggestions on my right monitor about how to finish an input I have in the center monitor!

Any way to tell Mathematica explicitly what monitor to use?

I am using Windows 10.

edit: Forgot to say that I have no such problematic behavior with any of my other applications, so this isn't a systematic issue for me.

Comment: Please mention your operating system.

Comment: Windows 10 Home

Comment: Using the "current" monitor is the default behavior.  It sounds like something wonky is happening, and this would be better suited with support than MSE.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? Would be helpful if you posted the solution, if you did.  I have the same issue and googling doesn't seem to do it.